# move row to last row of other sheet based on checkbox

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

can anyone help me please - I need to move row to another sheet based on checkbox.
I found code and it works but it moves row to the and of dest sheet.

```
function onEdit(e){
  var src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = e.range;
  if (src.getName() != "calculations" || r.columnStart != 13 || r.rowStart == 1) return;
  var dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("orders");
  src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,12).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,2,1,13));
  src.deleteRow(r.rowStart); 
}
```

I tried to determine last row of destination sheet but after adding this in code it does not works

```
function onEdit(e){
  var src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = e.range;
  if (src.getName() != "calculations" || r.columnStart != 13 || r.rowStart == 1) return;
  var dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("orders");
 
  var rng = dest.getRange("B1:M").getValues();
  var lrIndex;
  for(var i = rng.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    lrIndex=i;
    if(!rng[i].every(function(c){ return c == ""; })){
    break;
    }
    var lr = lrIndex + 1;
  }
  
  src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,12).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.lr,1,1,12));
  src.deleteRow(r.rowStart); 
}
```

can anyone help me please?

Comment: try this `src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,12).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getDataRange().getNumRows()+1,1,1,12))`

Comment: thank you so quick reply. unfortunately this changes does not help. maybe I did not describe my problem properly - I have some data in sheet "calculations" from A to L column. I need when  I'll push on checkbox in column M move this row to another sheet at the last empty row (not at the end of sheet) of sheet "order" in column B:M.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is an error in the line:

```
src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,12).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.lr,1,1,12));
```

Since `lr` is a number, perhaps there should be:

```
src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,12).moveTo(dest.getRange(lr,1,1,12));
```

Just `lr` instead of `dest.lr`.

But I didn't try to run the script, it's just a guess.